# jquery tablesorter filter plugin

Tags: jquery, tablesorter

I am using the [tablesorter](http://tablesorter.com/docs/) jquery plugin paired with this great [tablesorter filter](http://github.com/jbritten/jquery-tablesorter-filter/tree/master) plugin.

I have a select box on my page that contains a list of all the columns of my table. I want to be able to limit the filter to only the selected column when the user chooses to select it.

So far I have attached an event to the select box like so:

```
$('#SelectedColumn').bind("change", columnSelected);
```

With a handler like so:

```
function columnSelected() {
  var selected = $(this).val();
  $.tablesorterFilter.defaults.filterColumns = [selected];
}
```

This does correctly set the default value for the filter column but when the filter happens it doesn't actually use that value. It appears the plugin allows you to set filtered columns only on construction. Or my jquery newbiness cant figure out how to get at the bit of data I need to flip.

Comment: Same problem.  I desperately wish there was a concise example including all HTML, JS and references... this is a nightmare.

Comment: @ScottBeeson Try out my [fork of tablesorter](http://mottie.github.io/tablesorter/docs/). It has a [filter widget](http://mottie.github.io/tablesorter/docs/example-widget-filter.html) that might work for you ~ check out the `filter_onlyAvail` option.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

this got me what I wanted in a brute force sort of way. Still looking for a better solution.

```
function columnSelected() {
  var selected = $(this).val();
  $('#GoToTextBox').val('').focus();
  if (selected == 'Any') {
    $table.get(0).config.filter[0].filterColumns = null;
  } else {
    $table.get(0).config.filter[0].filterColumns = [selected];
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I work width jFilterSelect the filters for Tablesorter:

http://www.jordigirones.com/131-filtros-desplegables-con-tablesorter.html

Comment: But this filter does not work with multiple tables on a page. The selects retrieve unnecessary data from foreign columns of other tables. Does anybody know a workabout?

Answer (score 0):

I had same problem. On change event of select box, just reload the page and your problem will be solved.

```
<select name="search" id="search" onchange="refreshPage()" >

function refreshPage(){
        location.reload();
}
```